# jQuery UI Toggle Hover Not Alway Toggling

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

In the following demo, I'm using jQuery UI toggle to have a caption appear on hover and hide when not hovering over that image. While it initially appears to work. If you move your mouse quickly over the boxes and on to another the previous boxes caption sometimes stays open rather than hiding. Is there a fix for this issue, such as requiring greater/lesser delay or something else to guarantee that the caption will always disappear when your mouse is not over the image?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BNdggv

```
$( ".product" ).hover(function() {
  $(this).find( ".product-caption.odd" ).toggle( "slide",{direction:"left"},500);
  $(this).find( ".product-caption.even" ).toggle( "slide",{direction:"right"},500);

});
```

Comment: Please include ALL relevant code in the question itself.  This includes the HTML that you are attempting to run your jQuery against (relevant HTML portion).  It's important because if codepen.io goes away or your link this question because completely useless to future readers.

Comment: I believe the answer will relate to just this piece of javascript, but if the answer ends up involving changes to the HTML or CSS I can certainly answer that particular code to the question before marking as correct.

Comment: [Please read the help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add in a call to stop() before toggle() to keep from stacking up animations.

`$(this).find( ".product-caption.odd" ).stop().toggle( "slide",{direction:"left"},500);`

Comment: That's it! I new it would be something simple. Still learning a lot of those basics. Thanks so much. I'll mark this as correct after the min required time.

Comment: If your project (supported browsers) will allow it you could achieve a very similar animation using CSS.

Comment: I think CSS may be better solution as with jquery it goes out-of sync after few fast mouse movements. I had tried `stop` but did not suggest as it fails in these conditions. Though will be fine under normal interactions.

Answer (score 1):

Try utilizing `.stop()`

```js
$(".product").hover(function() {
  $(this).find(".product-caption.odd").stop(true, true).toggle("slide", {
    direction: "left"
  }, 500);
  $(this).find(".product-caption.even").stop(true, true).toggle("slide", {
    direction: "right"
  }, 500);
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 0;
}
.product-caption {
  width: 50%;
  height: 230px;
  background: #fff;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}
.product-caption.even {
  float: right;
}
.product-caption h3 {
  color: #5C5C5C;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.product-caption p {
  color: #9B9B9B;
}
.product-caption a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #F8981D;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.product {
  background-image: url(https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=52&txt=554%C3%97230&w=554&h=230);
  width: 554px;
  height: 230px;
}
.btn {
  border: 1px solid red;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="product">
  <div class="product-caption odd">
    <h3>One</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum.</p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#">Link</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<hr />

<div class="product">
  <div class="product-caption even">
    <h3>Two</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum.</p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#">Link</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<hr />

<div class="product">
  <div class="product-caption odd">
    <h3>Three</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum.</p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#">Link</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNPXeE

Comment: Thank you, that was it. Another use posted the stop suggestion right before you did, otherwise would have marked yours as correct.